# How do I edit Network Solution's DNS settings to allow no-www?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain registered through Network Solutions, foo.com.  I have it setup to point to a Blogger account I have setup.  I followed the instructions at:

- [How do I use a custom domain name on my blog?](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55373)

It loads http://www.foo.com fine.

But when I goto http://foo.com, it redirects to a subdomain that no longer exists (example: http://abc.foo.com).  I think it's from an old DNS setting I had setup at 1&1 hosting a while ago.  I no longer have access to my 1&1 account, so I can't view what DNS settings were in place.

**How do I edit the DNS Settings at Network Solutions so that http://foo.com also points to where http://www.foo.com also points to?**

Comment: Have you asked Network Solutions about this? Chances are they can help you.

Comment: I have not.  I've just been tweaking the DNS records to get this to work, which with my latest CNAME addition, seems to have resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a CNAME record.  So whenever http://abc.foo.com occurs, it redirects back to http://www.foo.com.

```
Host Aliases (CNAME Records)
Alias a domain name for another domain.

Alias                 TTL      Refers to Host Name

abc.foo.com         7200     www.foo.com
```

This seems to have fixed my problem for me.

Comment: This is **not a redirect**. Unless you have code in your HTTP configuration that redirects all non www prefixed traffic, it'll just be another way to access you're site. Users will see abc.foo.com; not www.foo.com.

Comment: I don't know anything about code in an HTTP configuration since this the site is hosted by Blogger (blogspot.com).  Also, I'm not sure I'm using the term 'redirect' correctly.  Previous to this CNAME addition, http://foo.com loaded the url http://abc.foo.com, which doesn't exist, a Google error page occurs.  Now typing in http://foo.com brings up http://www.foo.com.  I'd rather it be http://foo.com, but I think Blogger requires www.

Answer (score 2):

DNS and HTTP are completely separate protocols.

HTTP handles redirects. So if the url is changing (redirect) it's in the HTTP Server configuration.

DNS handles A & C-Name records; and the default record for foo.com must exist as it redirect. Sounds like DNS is setup correctly (probably).